# Manually Install Zend Optimizer in WAMP

Tags: php, zend-framework

How to install zend optimizer manually, actually i downloaded the zend optimizer.dll file and putted in the ext folder under wamp/bin/php/php-vr/ext and give the path in php.ini file like [Zend]

```
zend_extension = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.12/ext/zendoptimizer.dll"
```

but still it is not showing under the phpinfo().

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart your web server? Modifications to the php.ini are not taken into account until your web server restarts.